# BigQuery request calculating unique volume for a visited url

Tags: google-bigquery, intersection

I have a BigQuery table with this schema: user_id, url. This table contains like 800M+ rows.
This table represents an url visited by a user.
I have a list of word and I woud like to extract the urls containing any of these words, and the number of user who visited each url.
This part is ok I guess it's a simple query:

```
SELECT url, COUNT(DISTINCT(user_id)) AS uu FROM `table` WHERE (url like '%word1%' OR url like 'word2%' OR url like '%word3%') GROUP BY url
```

(If I wanted to have the number of total distinct users, summing these number would be wrong as it's possible some user have visited multiple urls containing these word.)
What I would like then it's to be able, in a UI, to unselect some of these urls I found and to see the total remaining volume, deduplicated, every time a user select/unselects a url.
What I could do is take the remaining urls that are still selected and run this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(user_id)) AS uu FROM `table` WHERE (url like == url1 OR url == url2 OR url == url3)
```

I guess this would work well but I can't do that: I have to suppose the user will select/unselect multiple time and the cost to run this query every time is too high. Also it might
run for a long time.
Do i have a way to do this ? May be having something precalculated could help but what ?

Answer (score 1):

If you need exact total distinct users on the one hand and a dynamic selection of URLs on the other hand, the only sort of optimization I could think of is to work on a smaller, deduped table.
If you have a lot of duplicate (user_id, url) pairs, you could populate an intermediate table with `SELECT DISTINCT url, user_id from table` and work with that.
Potentially you can further optimize by normalizing and shortening the URLs (e.g., remove URL parameters, lowercase, remove domain name if all are under the same one).

Perhaps, depending on your use case, you may only care about URLs above a certain level of activity, then you could further reduce rows like this:

```
WITH user_urls as (
SELECT DISTINCT
    user_id,
    url,
    count(distinct user_id) over (partition by url) as url_user_count
  FROM table
)
SELECT *
FROM user_urls
WHERE url_user_count>1000
```